# Inefficient SQL where query when using Breeze, OData and EF6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, odata, breeze

I have a WebApi 2 OData service with a breeze controller that is creating an inefficient where clause on my SQL Server.  The example I have:

`breeze.EntityQuery.from('GetIndividual').where('NameLast', 'startsWith', 'turn')`

Which will create a seemingly correct OData request as:

`GetIndividual?$filter=startswith(NameLast%2C%27turn%27)%20eq%20true&`

When profiling the query ran against the DB server the resulting `WHERE` clause is:

```
FROM   [PTY].[v_Individual] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  (CASE
      WHEN ([Extent1].[NameLast] LIKE 'turn%' /* @p__linq__0 */ ESCAPE '~') THEN cast(1 as bit)
      WHEN (NOT ([Extent1].[NameLast] LIKE 'turn%' /* @p__linq__0 */ ESCAPE '~')) THEN cast(0 as bit)
    END) = 1 /* @p__linq__1 */
```

Which should get the correct result, but I was expecting a `WHERE` clause similar to:

```
FROM   [PTY].[v_Individual] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[NameLast] LIKE 'turn%' /* @p__linq__0 */ ESCAPE '~'
```

The issue is running the first where statement takes 48 seconds (resulting in a timeout) vs running the second which takes less than 2 seconds.

What I have tried so far:

- Messing with OData request Filter to see if it changed the where
  statement.
- Creating a custom function to use EF's StartsWith (this will send the
  correct where clause to SQL, but not a workable solution as I do not
  want to have to write a bunch of these for something I think is built
  into OData)

  ```
         public IQueryable<v_Individual> GetTest(string searchTerm)
     {
         return _contextProviderModel.Context.v_Individual.Where(i => i.NameLast.StartsWith(searchTerm));
     }
  ```
- Trying Various Breeze settings I could find through the Google web
- Indexes on columns within the SQL tables

Is there a way to force OData (or Breeze) to parse that request and use the built in EF6 Starts with so the correct Where statement is send to SQL?  I do not know if this is important but EF is querying SQL views instead of the tables directly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is an OData issue because its [v.2. query syntax](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) requires that you express "startsWith" (and all function predicates) as boolean expressions. That's why you have that "eq true" in `startswith(NameLast,"turn") eq true`.

To make matters worse, apparently EF feels the need to turn that into the awful SQL you show when it too should be able to resolve the expression to the simpler `LIKE` form.

Very annoying.

They changed that [in v.3](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/). Unfortunately, Breeze OData query string generation is for the lowest common denominator ([v.2](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)) which is prevalent in the wild (and also understood by OData v.3 and v.4 providers). At this time, there is no way to tell Breeze to use the v.3 syntax.

> In a future version of Breeze you will be able to configure the client-side OData behavior to match the version of OData your server understands.

### What to do?

If you expect to query `NameLast` routinely, it deserves an index anyway.

If you know you'll be using OData v.3 or later, you can patch *breeze.debug.js*.

In Breeze versions up to v.5.0.0, search for "eq true" and you should find something like:

```
if (filterQueryOp == FilterQueryOp.Contains) {
    return filterQueryOp.operator + "(" + v2Expr + "," + v1Expr + ") eq true";
} else {
    return filterQueryOp.operator + "(" + v1Expr + "," + v2Expr + ") eq true";
}
```

Lop off the "eq true" so it becomes:

```
if (filterQueryOp == FilterQueryOp.Contains) {
    return filterQueryOp.operator + "(" + v2Expr + "," + v1Expr + ")";
} else {
    return filterQueryOp.operator + "(" + v1Expr + "," + v2Expr + ")";
}
```

> Yes ... you'll have to re-patch every time you upgrade Breeze until we provide the OData version option.

As of Breeze v.5.1.0 (coming soon), the code is a little different but just look for "eq true" and make the same change. The cool thing about this is the new "uriBuilder" adapter that is plugable. So you could create your own version and just plug that in.

Everything else I can think of involves interventions that seem pretty challenging to me. Sorry.

BTW, which version of EF are you using? If not v.6, you might try that. They added many optimizations, one of which might cover for this case.

Comment: Thanks for information, since I am using v.3+ I have made the modification to breeze.debug and the change seems to have improved the performance.